# SSL with Let's Encrypt, Apache and ProjectShield not working for WWW

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have a site behind ProjectShield, for www and bare domain.

Without https, it is working for www and bare domain.

Under https, is only working for the bare domain, **not working for www**, and that is my problem.

ProjectShield says my site is running without issues.

[image]

This is my Apache config for SSL:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/web
        SSLEngine On

        <Directory /var/www/web/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/web/some-path/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Another report which shows more data about the cert:

[image]

I already added my certificates to ProjectShield, and it reports that bare domain and www are protected.

[image]

So currently I don't know what else I have to do to make the SSL work for www, that is the preferred path for my client.

In Chrome it says ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. Firefox says "Secure Connection Failed". But as I said, **only for www**.

Also both www and the bare domain are poiting to the same address suggested by ProjectShield: 35.244.174.46.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your config. Obfuscating the domain part, when that's actually the most important part with this issue is not really helpful though. If I am not mistaken, the domain you are working with is "planv.com.ec" and that loads perfectly fine for me via HTTPS for the domain, and for the www. subdomain.

I did notice that you changed the DNS record recently and this needs up to 48 hours to propagate globally.

Comment: Thanks @Darthur I was trying to somehow protect the name of my client, just in case... However, you are right in everything. It seems to be a cache issue because I had tested the SSL in many services and it says the configuration is ok, but I'm not able to see it yet from my side. How do you know it was planv? Did you check my previous questions? Just curious.

Comment: You are most likely unable to see it from your end because your computer considers the domain still hosted at the previous location. You can either wait for the DNS change to propagate on your end, or manually force your computer to resolve it from the new location by altering your computer's hosts file. The server key and certificate data, in your screenshot above, has a "DNS CAA" with a "policy host" property which points to planv. I understand your position, but when asking for help of this kind, you do need specific details.

Comment: You are most welcome bud. I hope all works out once the DNS changes on our end :)